# Outlook Mapi access shared contacts

Tags: c#, outlook, shared, mapi

I want to import contacts from Outllok via Mapi.
First step with standard contact is no problem:

```
MAPIFolder contactObjects = 
outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
foreach (ContactItem contactObject in contactObjects.Items) {
    ... import contact ...
}
```

In a second step I additionally want to import shared contacts. Only thing I found was using

```
OpenSharedItem(sharedContacts.vcf)
```

but I don't know the name of the file (shared item) I want to open.
Does someone know how to access shared contacts and can help me out?

Tobi

---

Update:

Thanks for the hint with the vcf-Files. But where do I find them?

---

Update2:

I played around with OutlookSpy. I got access to the folder with shared contacts, but only by knowing the id (which is of course different for other users):

```
var ns = outlookObj.GetNamespace("MAPI");
var flr = ns.GetFolderFromID("00000000176A90DED92CE6439C1CB89AFE3668F90100D1AD8F66B576B54FB731302D9BB9F6C40007E4BAC5020000");

foreach (var contactObject in flr.Items) {
       ...
}
```

How do I get access to the folder without knowing the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution to the question as it is asked in the title is almost simple.
You just need to call:

```
Recipient recip = Application.Session.CreateRecipient("Firstname Lastname");
MAPIFolder sharedContactFolder = Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
```

Because this does not solve my problem I will ask [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526329/how-to-query-users-recipients-sharing-contacts-with-current-outlook-user)!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to either explicitly parse the vCard files or you can use Redemption (I am its author) - it allows to import vCard files using [RDOContactItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOContactItem.htm).`Import` - http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm#methods

Answer (score 0):

I have done some programming to get contact from outlook.
I am giving you some example code to help you up with this ..It is not excatly want you want but i think this will help you with your problem...

```
  using System.Collections.Generic; 

// ... 

private List<Outlook.ContactItem> GetListOfContacts(Outlook._Application OutlookApp) 

    { 
    List<Outlook.ContactItem> contItemLst = null; 
    Outlook.Items folderItems =null; 
    Outlook.MAPIFolder mapiFoldSuggestedConts = null; 
    Outlook.NameSpace nameSpc = null; 
    Outlook.MAPIFolder mapiFoldrConts = null; 
    object itemObj = null; 

    try 
    { 

        contItemLst = new List<Outlook.ContactItem>(); 
        nameSpc = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); 
        // getting items from the Contacts folder in Outlook 
        mapiFoldrConts = 
             nameSpc.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts); 

        folderItems = mapiFoldrConts.Items; 
        for (int i = 1; folderItems.Count >= i; i++) 
        { 

            itemObj = folderItems[i]; 
            if (itemObj is Outlook.ContactItem) 
                contItemLst.Add(itemObj as Outlook.ContactItem); 
            else 
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(itemObj); 
        } 

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems); 
        folderItems = null; 
        // getting items from the Suggested Contacts folder in Outlook 
        mapiFoldSuggestedConts = nameSpc.GetDefaultFolder( 

             Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSuggestedContacts); 

        folderItems = mapiFoldSuggestedConts.Items; 

        for (int i = 1; folderItems.Count >= i; i++) 
        { 

            itemObj = folderItems[i]; 
            if (itemObj is Outlook.ContactItem) 
                contItemLst.Add(itemObj as Outlook.ContactItem); 

            else 
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(itemObj); 
        } 
    } 

    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    } 

    finally 
    { 

        if (folderItems != null) 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems); 
        if (mapiFoldrConts != null) 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mapiFoldrConts); 
        if (mapiFoldSuggestedConts != null) 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mapiFoldSuggestedConts); 
        if (nameSpc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nameSpc); 
    } 

    return contItemLst; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I already do this. It is not the problem to import standard or suggested contacts, but to read shared contacts.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                NameSpace mapiNamespace = outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");

                foreach (Store store in mapiNamespace.Stores)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var folder = store.GetRootFolder();

                        foreach(MAPIFolder subfolder in folder.Folders)
                        {
                            if ( subfolder.Name == "Inbox")
                            {
                                foreach(dynamic message in subfolder.Items.Restrict("[MessageClass]='IPM.Sharing'"))
                                {
                                        if (message.Class == 104)//SharingItem
                                        {
                                            Folder sharedFolder = message.OpenSharedFolder();
                                            if (sharedFolder.DefaultMessageClass == "IPM.Contact")
                                            {
                                               //this is your folder
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This method searches for shared contacts emails in the inbox, and then opens the folders from those emails, I don't think this is the best solution because there might be other ways contacts are shared. I now use ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane solution and I open the outlook app if it is not opened and I close it after I get the contacts.

Answer (score -1):

I share a way to get files from outlook

```vb
Sub MoverCorreoALM()

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim namespace As Object
    Dim inbox As Object
    Dim items As Object
    Dim item As Object
    Dim attachment As Object
    Dim saveFolder As String

    ' Ruta de la carpeta de destino
    saveFolder = "C:\MiCarpeta\"

    ' Inicializar Outlook
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set namespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inbox = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' Carpeta de entrada

    ' Filtrar correos con asunto que contiene "ALM" y un solo archivo adjunto Excel que comienza con "Estatus "
    Set items = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Subject] Like '%ALM%' AND [Attachments.Count] = 1 AND [Attachments.Item(1).FileName] Like 'Estatus *.xls*'", True)

    ' Buscar el último correo (más reciente)
    items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False

    ' Procesar el correo más reciente que cumple con los criterios
    If items.Count > 0 Then
        Set item = items(1) ' Tomar el correo más reciente

        ' Guardar el archivo adjunto en la carpeta de destino
        Set attachment = item.Attachments(1)
        attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & attachment.FileName

        ' Mover el correo a la carpeta "CarpetaALM"
        item.Move namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("CarpetaALM")
    Else
        MsgBox "No se encontraron correos que cumplan con los criterios.", vbInformation
    End If

    ' Limpiar objetos
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set namespace = Nothing
    Set inbox = Nothing
    Set items = Nothing
    Set item = Nothing
    Set attachment = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**