# How to query Users/Recipients sharing Contacts/Calendars with Current Outlook User?

Tags: c#, outlook, shared, mapi

As I mentioned in a [former Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193374/outlook-mapi-access-shared-contacts) it is no problem to get shared contacts in Outlook via MAPI. But this is only possible, if you know the Users/Recipients sharing contacts (or also calendar) with the Current Outlook User.

Now back to my question: How can I get a list of Recipients sharing their contacts with me?

With the list I would do a foreach creating the Recipients and than access the shared folder.

```
// Get recipients    
IList<string> recipientsSharingContacts =  **???** ;

// Import/Read shared contacts 
foreach (string recip in recipientsSharingContacts){

    // Open Shared Folder
    MAPIFolder sharedContactsFolder = 
      Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)

    // Import Contacts 
    ...

}
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is interested in the solution, here is how I do it:

```
ContactsModule module = (ContactsModule)outlookObj.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleContacts);
foreach (NavigationGroup navigationGroup in module.NavigationGroups) {
     foreach (NavigationFolder navigationFolder in navigationGroup.NavigationFolders) {
          foreach (var item in navigationFolder.Folder.Items) {
                     // Found Folders are: Contacts, Suggested Contacts and Shared Contact Folders


                     // Import/Read ContactItems
                     ...
                }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you will only see the mailboxes of the users explicilty opened by the current user. It will not give you all the mailboxes that *can* be opened because the current user has the right to open their mailboxes.

Comment: this throws the following exception on outlook 2003. I have not tested 2007 yet, but I think it only works on 2010. 


Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Explorer.get_NavigationPane()

Comment: This works fine in 2007 SP2. The biggest Problem with this is, that there is a need of an ActiveExplorer which can be fatal if you call it from outside outlook.